# Where does Ant set its 'java.home' (and is it wrong) and is it supposed to append '/jre'?

Tags: java, ant, centos, environment-variables

Okay, I'm using Ant version 1.7.1 (default install) on CentOS 6.3:

```
[theuser@dev-ingyhere ~]$ ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on August 24 2010
[theuser@dev-ingyhere ~]$ cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
```

I have `JAVA_HOME` set and I run `ant`:

```
[theuser@dev-ingyhere ~]$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17 ; echo $JAVA_HOME ;
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17
[theuser@dev-ingyhere ~]$ ant -diagnostics | grep java\\.home
java.home : /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre
```

This is even more fun:

```
[theuser@dev-ingyhere ~]$ export JAVA_HOME=/a/fools/folly ; echo $JAVA_HOME ; ant -diagnostics | grep java\\.home
/a/fools/folly
java.home : /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre
[theuser@dev-ingyhere ~]$  env | grep JAVA
JAVA_HOME=/a/fools/folly
```

So, I do get one thing -- apparently [Oracle's Java 7 Javadoc for Class System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) is WRONG (aghast!) where it describes the `java.home` System Property as the "Java installation directory." I know that because the [Java(TM) Tutorials for System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) describes the `java.home` System Property as the "Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)." In other words the `JAVA_HOME` in the environment does not necessarily equal `java.home` in the JVM System Properties. (What sets that?!)

**QUESTION: Where and how does `Ant` get/set the system property `java.home`?**

Comment: Well, the "java.home" value reported by Ant is actually directly from java.lang.System. The code starts on line 328 in the Diagnostics class of Apache Ant 1.7.1. So, this is really a Java question.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, you can work around it by accessing the system environment property within Ant using ${env.JAVA_HOME}. Alternately, specify java in the Javac Task by setting the executable property to the javac path and the fork property to yes (see Ant's Javac Task Documentation). You can probably also change how JVMs are recognized in the system by following this guide, then Ant should launch with the proper JVM: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Really a JVM internals question**

Since Ant is just echoing the java.lang.System properties (see comment above under original post), this is really a JVM question. The [Java HotSpot Virtual Machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html) is the core interpreter. Code is available online at [hg.openjdk.java.net](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/summary).

[On line 309 of the C++ code for HotSpot (os_linux.cpp)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/03e1b9fce89d/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp) there is a an `init_system_properties_values()` method in the `os` class. It does some mild heuristics to kind of sniff out the location for a variable named `home_path` which ends up being set to what Java users see as "java.home". Comments in the code indicate that '<java_home>/jre' is being formally specified as the java.lang.System property value for "java.home" (in the case of a JDK install).

Answer (score 0):

I had a JDK installed on a Windows box in d:\jdk but running its d:\jdk\bin\java.exe with -XshowSettings showed its built-in java.home pointing to the system-wide JRE install in c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91.  I suspect that I corrupted my install by deleting d:\jdk\jre without understanding the role of a private JRE vs public JRE.

Comment: Java 8 installs a little differently than earlier versions. In order to exert more control over executables for security reasons, Oracle installs java.exe, javaws.exe and javaw.exe in the %WINDOWS%\system32 folder. Additionally, the path is hardcoded into a data file at  C:\programdata\Oracle\Java\javapath. See the answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324486/properly-installing-java-8-along-with-java-7 for more info. So I don't really think this is an Ant-specific issue.

Comment: I did not rely on %PATH% to execute java.exe in my corrupt JDK install.  It was either my deletion of d:\jdk\jre or installing the 64-bit JDK on top of the 32-bit one that caused d:\jdk\bin\java.exe look for the source of its home elsewhere (in the registry, I guess).